# Using ggplot2, how do I make multiple lines show up in my grid graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]I'm new to plotting graphs in R. I'm working with code someone else has written and I'm updating/modifying it to update figures for an annual report. I have the following data but it has samples for every month from 2016 - 2019[image]:

```
# Groups:   Year, Month, Site, Reach, ReachID [33,264]
Year  Month Site      Reach           ReachID       Size          Mussels_m2
<fct> <ord> <fct>     <fct>           <ord>         <fct>              <dbl>
1 2019  Feb   Below SFD Downstream Weir Property Line Total mussels         2 
2 2019  Feb   Below SFD Downstream Weir Property Line >10 mm                2 
3 2019  Feb   Below SFD Downstream Weir Property Line 5-10 mm               2 
4 2019  Feb   Below SFD Downstream Weir Property Line <5 mm                 2 
5 2019  Feb   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  Total mussels         2 
6 2019  Feb   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  >10 mm                2 
7 2019  Feb   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  5-10 mm               2 
8 2019  Feb   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  <5 mm                 2 
9 2019  Mar   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  Total mussels       174.
10 2019  Mar   Below SFD Upstream Weir   Release Pool  >10 mm              174.
```

The code I'm using is:

```
ggplot(releasereach2019, aes(x = Month, y = Mussels_m2, color = Size, group = 
Size)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(ReachID ~ .) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,8000,2000)) +
  labs(x = NULL, 
      y = "Mussel Density (m^2)",
      title = "Mussel Density Below SFD in 2019")
```

With this code, only the <5 mm value will plot in the graph, not the other sizes. I'm wondering what I can do to get the rest of the size values to plot. I've tried group = Size in geom_line() but it is still the same. The legend seems fine. Ideally I would like a graph similar to what is attached to this post with all the lines showing.

Comment: I see several sizes in the plot shown. What's the issue? If that isn't the plot you're talking about, can we see the problematic one?

Comment: I noticed you used scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,8000,2000)), are all your y-values within 0-8000 ?

Comment: Hello, I will update the problematic one.

Answer (score 0):

With the data you just provided is hard to work with, so I just created a whole new data frame, thats why there is only two faceted grids (pool and line). **Your code is ok**, but you could improve some things:

1. To order your month you should provide R with Date data or it will order them alphabetically, to solve this you can use from `dplyr` library `mutate()` and `factor()` 
   funtion.
2. This is just because I love to complicate myself in the axis text, to put a superscript you can use `expression()` and `^`  for example a² would be `expression("a"^"2")`.

The code it would be like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

releasereach2019%>%
  arrange(Mussels_m2)%>% mutate(Month=factor(Month,levels=c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")))%>%
ggplot(aes(x = Month, y = Mussels_m2, color = Size,group=Size)) +
geom_point()+
geom_line()+
facet_grid(ReachID ~ .) +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,8000,2000)) +
labs(x = NULL, 
     y = expression(paste("Mussel Density (m"^"2",")")),
     title = "Mussel Density Below SFD in 2019")
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Hello thank you for replying. Earlier in my code I did this by using: gathered.surface$Month <- factor(gathered.surface$Month,
                                 levels = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May','Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'),ordered = TRUE)

Comment: The gathered.surface is the master dataset with several years of data in it while the release reach data is just for 2019. I used releasereach2019 <- filter(releasereach, Year == 2019) to extract the 2019 data.